# evaluate power series and uniform convergence proof

Tags: power-series, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

I have 2 questions with one of them being a bit confusing the first one is 
prove that the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\cos(z/n^5)/n!$$  converges uniformly on D(0,1)

And the second question this is all the info I have

Calculate $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n/2^n$$

For this one I think I have to use contour integrals  $$\int_{\gamma } f(z)dz=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z^{n}dz$$

but im not sure what to do with that

Comment: Please, post only one question in one post. Posting several questions in the same post is discouraged and such questions may be put on hold, see [meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6464/posting-multiple-questions-as-one).

Answer (score 0):

You should have posted two separate questions. Anyway, the answer to the second question is $\dfrac1{1-\frac z2}$, because, if $|z|<2$, then$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^n}{2^n}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac z2\right)^n=\frac1{1-\frac z2}.$$

The series of the first question converges uniformly in $D(0,1)$ indeed. Let $M=\sup_{|z|\leqslant 1}\bigl|\cos(z)\bigr|$. Then$$(\forall z\in D(0,1))(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):\bigl|\cos(z)\bigr|\leqslant M$$and therefore you can use the fact that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac M{n!}$ converges to deduce, from the $M$-test, that your series converges uniformly on $D(0,1)$.

Comment: thank you very much man should I post a different question for the first question?

Comment: @Elena I've answered to that question too, but please post distinct questions separately.